# React frontend unable to view the app on the network while fetching data from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, mern

I have a React frontend application that fetches data from MongoDB. The data fetching and display are working correctly on my local machine. However, I'm encountering an issue where I cannot access the application on my network.

Here's a summary of the setup:

The frontend is built using React.
I'm using Axios to make HTTP requests to a MongoDB backend.
The backend is implemented using Express and Mongoose.
In the frontend code, I have a BlogView component that fetches data from the MongoDB backend using the fetchPostData(), fetchRelatedPosts(), and fetchBlogList() functions. The data is fetched and displayed correctly when running the application locally.

On the backend, I have an Express server that connects to MongoDB using Mongoose. I have defined the necessary routes for fetching data from the Blog collection in the database.

However, when I try to access the application from other devices on the same network using the IP address of my local machine, I am unable to view the app. The requests to the backend are not reaching the server.

I have checked that both the frontend and backend are running and accessible on my local machine. I have also ensured that the necessary ports (e.g., port 3002) are open on my machine's firewall.

I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue and making the React application accessible on my local network. Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
Frontend snippet

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';
`your text`
`const BlogView = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const postId = parseInt(id);
  const [blogList, setBlogList] = useState([]);
  const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
  const [relatedPosts, setRelatedPosts] = useState([]);
  const currentIndex = blogList.findIndex((item) => item.idBlog === postId);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPostData();
    fetchRelatedPosts();
    fetchBlogList();
  }, []);

  const fetchPostData = () => {
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/posts/${postId}`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setPost(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const fetchRelatedPosts = () => {
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/posts?_limit=5&_page=1`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setRelatedPosts(response.data.items);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const fetchBlogList = () => {
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/read`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setBlogList(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

backend snippet

```
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const Blog = require("./Blog");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

app.post('/insert', async (req, res) => {
   code for inserting a new blog post
});

app.get('/posts/:id', async (req, res) => {
  code for retrieving a specific blog post by ID
});

app.get('/read', async (req, res) => {
   code for fetching all blog posts
});

app.listen(3002, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 3002');
});
```

`
and also in the network access I have added 0.0.0.0/0  ip address.Thanks in advance

Frontend (React):
In the frontend code, the following actions were taken:

Data fetching: The fetchPostData(), fetchRelatedPosts(), and fetchBlogList() functions were implemented to fetch data from the backend server using Axios.
State updates: The fetched data was stored in state variables (blogList, post, relatedPosts) using useState() hooks.
Rendering: JSX code was expected to render the fetched data on the frontend.
Expectations:

fetchPostData() was expected to fetch a specific blog post based on the postId parameter.
fetchRelatedPosts() was expected to fetch a list of related blog posts.
fetchBlogList() was expected to fetch a list of all blog posts.
The fetched data was expected to be stored in the corresponding state variables (blogList, post, relatedPosts).
The JSX code within the return statement was expected to render the fetched data on the frontend, presumably displaying the blog post and related posts.
Backend (Express with Mongoose):
In the backend code, the following actions were taken:

Server setup: An Express server was set up to handle HTTP requests.
Database connection: The server was connected to a MongoDB database using Mongoose.
Route definitions: Routes were defined to handle different endpoints for inserting, retrieving, and reading blog posts from the database.
Expectations:

Upon receiving a POST request to the /insert endpoint, a new blog post was expected to be inserted into the MongoDB database.
Upon receiving a GET request to the /posts/:id endpoint, the server was expected to retrieve a specific blog post based on the provided ID.
Upon receiving a GET request to the /read endpoint, the server was expected to fetch all blog posts from the database.